# Python rectangle packing

Tags: python, algorithms

I'm working on a project which involves packing multiple rectangles in a larger rectangle(the bounding box). Rectangles can't overlap with each other or with the boundaries of the bounding box. Rectangles can rotate, increasing the state space to `n! * 2^n` for problems of n rectangles.

I'm trying to write a Python program that 'solves' these problems, eg it should find all possible solutions given a set of rectangles and a bounding box. I'm using a depth-first search algorithm right now, but I feel like I'm missing a lot of optimisations to speed up my program. My algorithm works as follows:

1. I have a list with values representing the heights of the columns in the larger bounding box, initialised to all 0's.
2. I look for the first empty spot in the bounding box, which is represented by the column with the smallest value.
3. If the current rectangle fits in that spot, I 'place' the rectangle by increasing the height of the right columns by the height of the rectangle.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until no more rectangles can be fit and backtrack to other possible solutions.

In (pseudo-)code it looks like this:

```
def solve(rectangles):

    # Solution found
    if rectangles is empty:
        add_to_solutions()
        return

    position = find_first_empty_spot()
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        for r in [rectangle, rectangle.rotated()]:
            if rectangle fits at given position:
                place_rectangle_in_bounding_box(r)
                remove r from rectangles
                solve(remaining_rectangles)
                remove_rectangle_from_bounding_box(r)
```

Are the basics of my algorithm correct or am I missing some (obvious) improvements? It would be great to solve problems of sizes up to 20 rectangles but my current algorithm would take way too much time to solve them.

And: I'm trying to find 'all' possible solutions to the problem, I can't just stop after finding 'a' solution, so a lot of heuristics found in the literature are not applicable.

Comment: How about some dynamic programming: Lets say the large space is size N, and you have a list of rectangles L. after placing some rectangles you have n space remaining, and l rectangles. Once you figure out all the possible combinations that l rectangles can make in this space, then in the future when you come across the same situation, you already know the answer.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21282418/2521214 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18693107/2521214 for some ideas ,... what are the criteria ? is rotation needed? (rotated rectangles occupy usually more space

Comment: You may be interested by the [Survey on two-dimensional packing](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html) article.

Comment: What are you really after? The number of possible placements? The most dense packing (ie the packing with the smallest minimal bounding box)? A packing with a "high score" according to some scoring function? Making a list of 20!*2^20 packings sounds pretty unreasonable.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Where does the n! come from? If you have for example just one 2x1 rectangle and a 3x3 box, then there are 12 ways, not 2. And this is even assuming you're restricted to right angles and integers.

Comment: My explanation was probably not very clear: the area of the bounding box is exactly equal to the total area of all the rectangles. Im looking for all possible solutions to the problem, not just the first found. For a set of 10 rectangles, there are 10! of possible orders in which the rectangles can be placed. With the possibility that of rotation,the state space increases with a factor 2^10. Of course, using depth-first search and recursion, not all of the 10! * 2^10 are checked, but with sets of > 12 rectangles, my solver simply takes way too much time to generate a decent amount of results.

Comment: @Koen: I still do not get it - do the rectangles have different dimensions? If there are two rectangles of equal dimensions, does swapping them count as a different solution, or not? An example (maybe a sketch) would probably be helpful.

Comment: @DocBrown: the rectangles in the set have unique dimensions, squares are not allowed. This way, the state space for sets of the same number of rectangles is equal. Im not the best at explaining the exact problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are asking about is a well known problem which has a plethora of applications:  For example the task to minimize material waste in furniture production: Certain pieces (your list of rectangles) have to be cut out of boards of plywood in a given size (your bounding rectangle).  As you seem to have already figured out finding all possible solutions is a [combinatorial NP-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Therefore in the industry we usually don't insist on finding all possible solutions but instead use an [approximation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) which might of course not always deliver the best possible solution.  So currently the best answer I can give to your question is to point you to [this BPP](http://openopt.org/BPP) [example here](http://trac.openopt.org/openopt/browser/PythonPackages/OpenOpt/openopt/examples/bpp_2.py) illustrating the use of a solver from the open source [Python OpenOpt package](http://openopt.org/Welcome).

From my understanding your wish to enumerate all possible solutions is impossible to fulfill in an acceptable time even for a moderate number of saying 20 rectangles or so.  If this is not true I'm also eager to know and learn.